# MS Access loading values from a different table to control source in datasheet form

Tags: database, forms, ms-access

please bear with me; I'm not particularly confident with MS Access, although I am quite experienced with SQL Databases from website work.

For my sins, I have been tasked with developing a database which will unify the hundreds of spreadsheets which we currently use to record details of our clients, work, and other stuff... The database is established and built, but I am now working with the forms to allow data entry.

I have a datasheet form (we have a member of admin staff who is hell-bent on refusing to use forms, so a datasheet form seems to be the best way to appease her!) and it is bound to a specific table ('referrals') to allow a user to input data into that table. It looks like this:

[image: Form Field]

However, I need to be able to load values from another table ('pupil_details') into the 'UPN' field so that if a pupil already exists in the 'pupil_details' table, the user can pick that pupil and have their details automatically filled into the form for convenience.

The form's Record Source is currently:

```
SELECT referrals.*
FROM referrals;
```

The most obvious way to do this seemed at first to be to use a join query for the form's record source, along the lines of:

```
SELECT referrals.*, pupil_details.UPN
FROM referrals LEFT JOIN pupil_details ON referrals.UPN = pupil_details.pupil_id
```

and then use this as the control source but when I do this, it breaks the functionality of the form (displays all the records, prevents it being used to enter data)

So, can anybody suggest to me how I might be able to get the 'UPN' field to display a list of records based on this query when a user types into it:

```
SELECT pupil_details.UPN, pupil_details.name, pupil_details.date_of_birth FROM pupil_details
```

But then enter the details into the 'referrals' table when the user submits the form? Sort of like this that I mocked up in Photoshop:

[image]

I'm stumped, and half a day on Google has left me none the wiser... :(

Thanks!

Comment: You should use a continuous form, not a datasheet, it will give you a lot more control, but still look like Excel. Once you have the form, you can add a combobox to get the details you want. It is nearly always best to avoid Excel attitudes in Access.

Comment: Good tip! rebuilding the form as a continuous form, and using combo boxes has done exactly what I want! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a continuous form, not a datasheet, it will give you a lot more control, but still look like Excel. Once you have the form, you can add a combobox to get the details you want. It is nearly always best to avoid Excel attitudes in Access.

Comment: That was working nicely, and answered the original question prefectly, but a new development: I've hit the MS Access maximum form width, and can't fit all of my fields onto a continuous form... Any suggestions, or am I just going to have to beat the member of staff who makes a fuss about forms until she starts using them? :)

Comment: Well ... :) Do you really need all the fields? Would a second form with less relevant fields work?